# DB Permission: User can drop only their created db's?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to set permission against a user, which can create database and drop on their created databases neither any database. Any idea/suggestion ?

Comment: sorry ! cant understand. I have given sysadmin role to user through this can drop any db. I want to restrict to drop their only own created db's.

Comment: thats the answer: It is common that vendors ask for permission to create databases (or they applications need to create database) on your servers and most of DBAs I have seen immediately grant them dbCreator server role. But they are not aware that members of that role are able to DROP/ALTER any databases on the entire server regardless of whether or not you even have a user account in the database.Did you really want that? 

The right approach is to grant CREATE ANY DATABASE permission and then the user is able to DROP/ALTER he/she owns.

Answer (score 1):

to grant use privliges to create database you can use the following command:

```
use [master]
GO
GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO [LoginName]
GO
```

To drop it you need to make sure the user has owner privileges on the database, you can use the command `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::db TO [LoginName];`

Comment: You can make them the owner using `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::db TO [LOGIN];`